# What ports should svchost be allowed to use? Using Windows Firewall in Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, firewall, windows-firewall, svchost

I've been following [this](http://hardenwindows10forsecurity.com/) guide to harden Windows 10.  I'm caught on one part.

For allowing Windows Firewall outbound connections it says to, for svchost, to create 2 rules.  One which allows UDP with port 53. And the other to allow TCP with ports 80, 443.

My question is, are these the correct ports to allow for svchost.exe?

Thank you.

Comment: That link doesn't look very reliable to me. How many times do he say "I don't understand what it does.", "don't understand how it works", "I am not familiar with it, so I don't know what is normal, ie what should be showing and what shouldn't be. " ...

Comment: Indeed, which is why I'm double checking on this.  Thank you.